# how to fetch data based on and condition

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to get all the ID's where the value is equal to hello & world.
Since I have this data structure, how can i get this data?

```
id value
1   hello
1   world
2   hai
3   hello
3   world
```

Expected Output

```
id
1
3
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output you want?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self `join` on `id` to check if records with same `id` have `hello` and `world` in `value` column.

Following query will give you desired output.

```
select t1.id 
from   @table t1 
       inner join @table t2 
               on t1.id = t2.id 
where  t1.value = 'hello' 
       and t2.value = 'world'
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/MNVXT33140)

**Output**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE value = 'hello' OR value = 'world'
```

or Unique id's

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE value = 'hello' OR value = 'world' GROUP BY id
```

Another option, but I'm sure this isn't very efficient.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE) AS concatvalues FROM testtable GROUP BY id) mytable2 WHERE concatvalues LIKE '%hello%' AND concatvalues LIKE '%world%'
```

Comment: I dont think this works! as the data is id : value format

Comment: @terry I've changed my answer based on your expected output. You might want to add GROUP BY id

Comment: How can it be OR condition? I need all the ID's with both hello and world values

Comment: I've re-read your question and I think I've misunderstood what you meant.